# Video streaming through libnice and gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, stun, turn, libnice

I want to stream video from IP camera to remote PC which is behind the NAT. For this purpose i am using, libnice and gstreamer.

On one end, I have implemented the below pipeling.

**rtspsrc <-> nicesink**

Remote client pipeline

**nicesrc <-> rtph264depay <-> h264parse <-> ffdec_h264 <-> autovideosink**

But, I am not able to get the video stream on the remote client.
I am getting the video packet on nicesrc element on remote client, but by above pipeline, I am not able to see the video.

#### How do i come to know packets are coming on nicesrc element on remote client:

I am getting the buffer length print in the receive callback of the libnice. from there, i am also able to record the video in h264 format and play it. but live streaming is not happening by above mentioned pipeline on remote client.

I have also tried to include the capfilters in the gstreamer pipeline without any success.
Any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: is this a software question, network question or programming question?

Comment: @Raptor This is a gstreamer programming question.

Comment: @JagsVG, are you pipelines working locally via UDP? I mean if you connect via UDP on same machine - do you see the video on client?